# Code for "if mouse released on picture, select picture. Mouse released again, then place picture"

Tags: java, if-statement

I need to write a code that places a picture on the screen, plays a sound once the picture has been clicked, and anywhere you click after that will place the sticker. I am done with the picture and sound portion but I am stumped on placing the sticker. I am currently trying to write a command `if (EZInteraction.wasMouseLeftButtonReleased() && hatsound.play()) {`. But it won't work and if I add parenthesis and change the code to `if (EZInteraction.wasMouseLeftButtonReleased()) && (hatsound.play()) {`, it will say error on token && invalid OnlySynchronized. Please help. This is my first semester taking CS. My code for the sound and placing sticker portion is

```
while(true) { //while loop is always true
    int clickX = EZInteraction.getXMouse(); // declare an integer variable called clickX and the X mouse coordinate integer is assigned to it
    int clickY = EZInteraction.getYMouse(); // declare an integer variable called clickY and assign to it the Y mouse coordinate integer

    if (EZInteraction.wasMouseLeftButtonReleased()){  //if the left mouse button is released then
        if (hatPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){ //if the left mouse button is release on this picture
            hatsound.play(); //then hatsound will play
        }
        if (EZInteraction.wasMouseLeftButtonReleased()) && (hatsound.play()) { //if left mouse released and hat sound plays then
            EZ.addImage("hat.png", clickX, clickY); //hat.png will be placed
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to find out if the sound has to play or not? I don't think `hatsound.play()` returns a `boolean`. You an do it by introducing a boolean variable in the following way.

```
int clickNum = 0;
boolean hatSoundPlay = false;
while(true) { //while loop is always true
    int clickX = EZInteraction.getXMouse(); // declare an integer variable called clickX and the X mouse coordinate integer is assigned to it
    int clickY = EZInteraction.getYMouse(); // declare an integer variable called clickY and assign to it the Y mouse coordinate integer

    if (EZInteraction.wasMouseLeftButtonReleased()){  //if the left mouse button is released then
        if (hatPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){ //if the left mouse button is release on this picture
            if (!hatSoundPlay) {
                hatsound.play(); //then hatsound will play
                hatSoundPlay = true;
            } else {
                EZ.addImage("hat.png", clickX, clickY); //hat.png will be placed
                hatSoundPlay = false;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

The best way though is to see the reference of the class playing the sound and to find out what are the methods and variables. What is the type of your `hatsound` variable?

Comment: The problem is not the sound but placing the picture after the sound plays. I want it to play a sound after I click the picture, then, the next time I release left click, place the picture that I just clicked. That is what I need help doing.

Comment: I edited the code. It uses `hatSoundPlay` boolean as a switch. If it's false (first click) It plays the sound and sets the variable to true. If click again, shows image and sets variable to false. And starts again...

Comment: Thank you for your help, but could you also tell me how to place the picture else where? Because the addImage will only add the hat.png if I click on the original picture again. It won't place a picture anywhere else except on the original sticker.